# Planarity in graphs

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

I am implementing a graph library and I want to include some basic graph algorithms to it. I have read about planar graphs and I decided to include to my library a function which checks if a graph is planar. I found in the web many efficient algorithms, but they all had the same drawback; they are very hard to implement. So this is my question: does it exist an algorithm for planarity check which is easy to understand and to implement?

**Note:** I write in C++

Comment: I think http://math.stackexchange.com would have been a better place to ask

Comment: The wikipedia article "Planarity testing" provides an overview of various techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a maths question, but anyway from the depths of my memory and from wikipedia

A finite graph is planar if and only if it does not contain a subgraph that is a subdivision of K5 (the complete graph on five vertices) or K3,3 (complete bipartite graph on six vertices, three of which connect to each of the other three).

Comment: Trying to find Kuratowski's forbidden minors (K_5 and K_3,3) is computationally expensive. A more efficient solution is to try to generate a planar embedding and when this fails then the graph is non-planar.